# Hot reload slow loading issues in Big Project

Tags: visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

I have Blazor web application which contain more than 150 razor page.I have installed visual studio 2022 community edition 17.3 version to get "**Hot Reload"** feature.Hot Reload working for small blazor web application which contain 5 to 1o razor page but when I run "Hot Reload" in big project (more than 150 razor page) then it takes time to reload (slow hot re loading which takes 55 seconds for small correction).Please advise if any one face this issues in visual studio 2022

Comment: Can you split your code out into a set of smaller structured UI libraries to restrict the amount of code that gets re-compiled on a save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's VS's problem, I also meet this problem from time to time. It seems that VS tries to detect all your changes on every single step in the debugger even though there have been no changes at all. According to the Microsoft, updating to the latest version can solve this problem. However, it didn't help. So, my choice is using ***dotnet watch run --verbose*** instead, it takes much less time. Maybe Microsoft can solve this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

With a launchsetting like the following it will work out just fine. Had exactly the same problem.

```
"Watch": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "dotnet.exe",
  "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
  "commandLineArgs": "watch run --verbose",
  "environmentVariables": {
     ...
  }
}
```